# NodeJS promise resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const f = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(4));

const g = () => {
  Promise.all(a.map((member) => f().then((res) => res)))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    });
}

g();
```

**Why do I not** need another then attached to `{return res;}` here?

I read that when you have a `return (something)`inside a then, another `then` must be attached, but its not the case here. Help?

Comment: The promise will figure out if you intended to map, or flatMap. So you can return a plain value and it will map; return a promise and it will flatMap.

Answer (score 3):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises. `.then` returns a promise. Therefore your mapping logic converts an array of numbers to an array of promises, exactly what you need.

`.then((res) => {return res;})` is completely unnecessary btw, `return f();` would suffice. You can even simplify your current code further to:

```
Promise.all(a.map(f)).then(result => console.log(result));
```

> I read that when you have a `return (something)` inside a `then`, another then must be attached

This has nothing to do with `.then`. `.then` simply returns a promise. To *access the result* of a promise you need to attach a handler via `.then`.

You don't need to do this here because you are passing the promises to `Promise.all`. You are accessing *that* result via `.then((result)=>{console.log(result)})`.

Comment: Why did you leave out the "return" in "map(f)"?

Comment: Because `(member)=>{ return f();}` is equivalent to `f` in your example. Or more general: Given `function foo() {}; function bar() { return foo(); }` then calling `bar()` is exactly the same as directly calling `foo()`. In your example, there is no need for the intermediate function `(member)=>{ return f();}`, you can pass `f` directly to `a.map`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I not need another then attached to `{return res;}` here?
>
> I read that when you have a `return (something)`inside a then, another
>   `then` must be attached, but its not the case here. Help?

There is another `.then()` attached to `Promise.all()`. Did you mean `.catch()` should be attached to avoid `Uncaught (in promise)`?

Note also, `Promise.all()` is not `return`ed from `g()` call, to further chain the `Promise`.

`.then()` and `.catch()` chained within `.map()` callback can be utilized to either handle error or rejected `Promise` and return a resolved `Promise` to `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`; or to `throw` current or new `Error()` to `Promise.all()` call.

The pattern can also be used to return all promises passed to `.map()`, whether resolved or rejected to `.then()`, without immediately calling `.catch()` chained to `Promise.all()`.

```js
function  f (index) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (index !== 4) resolve(4);
        else reject("err at index " + index)
    })
}

var a =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function  g () {
    return Promise.all(a.map((member, index)=>{
        return f(index).then((res) => {return res;})
              .catch(e => {console.log(e); throw new Error(e)})
    }))
    .then((result)=>{console.log(result); return result})
    .catch(e => {
      // handle error here, return resolved `Promise`,
      // or `throw new Error(e)` to propagate error to
      // `.catch()` chained to `g()` call
      console.log("handle error within g", e); 
      return "error " + e.message + " handled"});
}

g()
.then(data => {console.log(data) /* `error err at 4 handled` */ })
.catch(e => console.log("done", e));
```